# ¿Cómo crear a un div bordes laterales de 80% y centrarlo verticalmente?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Necesito crear un elemento que tenga la siguiente forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un div con borders laterales de aproximadamente 80% del tamaño del div y centrado verticalmente

Comment: Luis bienvenido a SOes. Nos gustaria saber que has hecho hasta el momento y en donde tienes problemas. Puedes revisar el articulo: [ask], para mas informacion.

Answer (score 0):

Espero que esto te pueda ayudar, saludos!

```css
.cuadro-amarillo{
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}
.cuadro-rojo{
  width: 80%; 
  height: 120%;
  background-color:red
}
```

```html
<div class="cuadro-amarillo">
  <div class="cuadro-rojo">
  </div>
</div>
```

[Enlace a mi codepen](https://codepen.io/fausto16/pen/aLVgyW)